# how to define a global "struct" variable in C

Tags: c, struct, global

I would like to define a global/public variable that is created by struct. I can not access user_list.x or y/z inside the main or any another function. when I debug the code below, I get the following error "request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union". How can I declare a global struct variable that I can access from different functions? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct routing {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
};
struct routing user_list[40];

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    user_list.x = 1;
    printf("user_list.x is %d",user_list.x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using an array of `struct` objects not a `struct` object.

Specify the array member you want to access:

```
int i = 0;

user_list[i].x = 1;
printf("user_list[i].x is %d",user_list[i].x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access by index to your array.

Try

```
user_list[i].x = 1;
printf("user_list[i].x is %d",user_list[i].x);
```

Where `i` is your index (previously defined, or "constant")